# Display everything including the modified result(s) of said array from user input

Tags: c++, arrays, string

There are 5 names in the array

- Sergio Ramos
- Federico Valverde
- Edin Hazard
- Carlos Henrico
- Ferland Mendy

What I need specifically done is the user enters the first name only out of the array. If it detects that the first name is in the array, then it flips the first and last name followed by "(c)". However, the user keeps entering first names until the letter "q" is pressed. Then the program takes the entire array and displays it in a list format (like the one above), but shows which names were flipped along with the rest.

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;
using namespace std;

void check(string[], int, string);
void display(string[], int);

int main()
{
    string lookup;
    const int arraySize = 5;
    string names[arraySize] = 
    { "Sergio Ramos", "Federico Valverde", "Edin Hazard", "Carlos Henrico", "Ferland Mendy" };
    do 
    {
        cout << "Type first name to lookup q to quit: ";
        cin >> lookup;
        check(names, arraySize, lookup);
    } while (lookup != "q");
}

void check(string str[], int size, string name) //To locate the first name and flip it
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        string full_name = str[i];
        if (full_name.find(name) != string::npos)
        {
            int pos = full_name.find(' ');
            string firstName = full_name.substr(0, pos);
            string lastName = full_name.substr(str[i].find_first_of(' ') + 1);
            cout << lastName << " " << firstName << "(c)" << endl;
        }
    }
}

void display(string str[], int size, string name) //To display all the names after user hits "q"
{
    
}
```

My code isn't finished because I don't know how to finish it.

Input: Sergio

Output: Ramos Sergio (c)

I know how to do the one from the example I showed you, but I don't know where to go from there. I need to display ALL of the names including the flipped one. I don't even know if I did the check function correctly either.

Comment: Please make sure to make descriptive titles.

Comment: I suggest you first write a function that takes a name, reverses it and returns it with the `(c)`, nothing but that, and test it with a very simple `main` function to see if it works, maybe `std::string flipName(std::string name);` where you just pass in the name and it returns the flipped name.  All of this other code with input statements, entering `q`, prompts, etc. is totally unnecessary at this point, and only makes things more confusing.  Once you have that function written, all you need to do is to then put it in a larger program and simply call that function.